# Iterating over a string input

Tags: c, validation, input, integer, fgets

I am trying to iterate over a string to see if the input is a whole number.

This is the code:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < strlen(buffer); i++) //Checking that each character of the string is numeric
    {
        if (!isdigit(buffer[i]))
        {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(valid == false)
    {
        printf("Invalid input!");
    }

    else
    {
        num = atoi(buffer);
        printf("The number entered is %d", num);
    }
```

The problem is that even if the input is correct, let us say 2, the output message is still "Invalid input!".

I am very frustrated right now.  I have tried using the atoi function, the strtol function and other methods so that I can validate a number and ensure that:

1) it is not a letter
2) it is a whole number

Please help me.  I have been trying to solve this problem for over 2 hours.

Comment: you need to post your isdigit code

Comment: the isdigit is a method provided by the ctype.h library.  I did not create it myself

Comment: This is obviously **not** *too localized*. The code snippet is obvious, the output is unexpected though.

Comment: Reading `man` pages helps. As well as learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: And it's still `int main(void)`.

Comment: @alk Thanks for pointing it out.  I forget every time.  I am kind of new to C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `fgets` reads a line, a `'\n'` (which is not a digit) may remain at the end of your string. You can remove it:

```
#include <string.h>

char *pend = strrchr (buffer, '\n');

if (pend != NULL) *pend = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kirilenko :)))  It solved the problem completely.  What is the code doing exactly.  Is it replacing \n with \0?

Comment: Thank you so much.  So pend is a data pointer to the null-terminating character and if pend is not null (null-terminating character found), it replaces it with \0?

Comment: It replaces the last newline character of the string with a `\0`. 
If no newline character is found, dereferencing `pend` would lead to undefined behavior, so we avoid such case.

Comment: Thanks again :)  Sorry if I ask such questions but I am kind of new to C.

Comment: @Matthew: No need to be sorry. If the question is well-asked, it's a pleasure to answer. ;-)